# Interpreting w3wp.exe thread-infos, does mscorwks.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x7688 has a negative impact

Tags: asp.net, iis, w3wp, process-explorer

I am trying to interpret the meaning of "mscorwks.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x7688". I guess it means, that the assembly loaded by the mscorworks.dll has no StrongName? If yes, does this have any negative impact for a web application?

Is it safe to assume that the thread count of 107 means, that web application needed at a peek a maximum of 107 concurrent threads to handle incoming requests?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An offset of 0x7688 strongly indicates that is not the correct name for method (and there is a symbol correctness issue).

107 threads seems very high, unless there is a lot of blocking going on when serving requests, perhaps time to perform some operations asynchronously?

Comment: I can't follow, why 0x7688 strongly indicates a non correct method name? Wouldn't that lead to a lot of exceptions? Aren't the symbols are only relevant in an debugging context? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hmm may be some threads are just not get closed properly? Its an 8 Core machine and since its an web application, with no long running processes, I don't see any advantage in asynchronous operations? Is it possible , that the threads are preserved for the current amount of parallel (inter)active sessions?

Comment: @Robert: having a method with more than 25kB of code (needed for that offset) is unlikely.